# What does "Go to town" mean?

Tags: terminology

I've played Diablo II since release and to me "Go to town" means open town portal, heal, sell items, brag a bit and maybe take a minute to relax. But the other gamers on the net seem to mean something else by that.

What does going to town mean these days?

Comment: Somebody added Diablo 2 tag to my question accidentally. Don't be confused by that, I already know what it means in that context, I'm asking about the rest of the possible gaming contexts.

Answer (score 5):

It could be slang.  [To proceed enthusiastically, vigorously, or expertly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to_town), similar to "Going all out".  As with many things in the English language, the meaning depends on the context in which it is used.

"Drink your potions and **go to town** on that monster!"  This is an example where it would mean go kill an enemy.

"After the enemy is dead, **go to town** and meet at the weapon shop."  This example would mean literally go back to the town.

For these "other gamers on the net", we would need to some examples to tell you exactly what those mean.

Comment: kind of fun that this saying is on *both* sides of the spectrum.. one being super aggressive and the other being retreating